# download.file works only over https

Tags: r, quantmod

I have a weird problem. I use `quantmod` package to get rates from "oanda" provider. It internally uses the `download.file` function, that fails with a message

> cannot open URL 'http://www.oanda.com/.....'

I was able to narrow the problem to:

```
> download.file("https://oanda.com", destfile="/tmp/gh")
trying URL 'https://oanda.com'
downloaded 95 KB

> download.file("http://oanda.com", destfile="/tmp/gh")
trying URL 'http://oanda.com'
Error in download.file("http://oanda.com", destfile = "/tmp/gh") : 
  cannot open URL 'http://oanda.com'
```

*Note the difference in `http`/`https` above*.

This is reproducible for any other domain. I am completely lost since I can’t google any trace of this to happen to anybody else. `wget` from the command line works perfectly for both addresses.

*Probably unrelated environment details:* I have `RCurl` installed. It’s being run from under local `shiny` server installed on AWS. Ubuntu 14LTS.

So, **how can I make `quantmod` to use `https` for it’s call or how can I make `download.file` to work with `http`?**

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried to set the `method` argument of `download.file()` to `"wget"` ?

Comment: Also, you can  try `options(download.file.method="wget")` before downloading with quantmod. Refer this: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/83 Also, as it is working fine with http on my Ubuntu16.04, updating curl might do the trick . I have curl 7.49.0

Comment: @R.S. Setting the `download.file.method` to `"wget"` in `options` helped. Thank you very much, would you please copy-paste this comment as answer so that I could accept it the future visitors?

Comment: @Chrisss I did not, since I did not realize how to make `quantmod` understand it. Wide-system `options` as suggested by R.S. helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting my comment above as answer.

Please refer to this bug report : http://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/83

It seems there is an issue with curl.

If wget is working fine, you can follow  the same advice and try the R command `options(download.file.method="wget")` to make  quantmod download using wget instead of curl.